# Running a Giraph job showing the following error

Tags: java, sockets, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, giraph

INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server debashis-Pseudo-Hadoop/127.0.1.1:22181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

14/06/17 13:07:28 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a problem, sometimes it does this and tries again and succeeds.  Have you looked at the logs?  Try something like the following from the command line to see them, you may need to pipe to a file as they're quite big.  Replace the application ID with the relevant numbers, you should be able to find this either in the console output or somewhere on Hue (or whatever you're using):

```
yarn logs --applicationId application_1399469361545_0003
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286105/how-do-i-handle-the-following-error-i-am-getting-while-executing-the-following-o